# Ant Media Server embed code doesn't work properly in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, webrtc, rtmp, ant-media-server-sdk

I'm using AMS 2.1. I want to use embed video code on my Wordpress page. But my embed code doesn't work properly. What is the main problem? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes WordPress system overrides to request with `https://`. So, if you request with `https://` and 5080 port, getting an error is normal.

You need to [enable SSL](https://github.com/ant-media/Ant-Media-Server/wiki/Installation#6-install-ssl-for-your-ant-media-server) with domain and 5443 port. It's the best case from IFrame.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://example.com:5443/WebRTCAppEE/play.html?name=JamesBondRTC" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```